# Can I control the mouse inside a virtual machine programatically without hijacking the cursor on my real machine?

Tags: python, selenium, mouse, virtualbox, sikuli

I am trying to automate an HTML5 application that checks at the location of the real cursor before it accepts a click.  I tried using Selenium in Python to automate clicks at various points on the canvas.  The buttons on the canvas change color the way they are supposed to when the mouse is over them when Selenium tries to click on them, but the click is only accepted if I have the real mouse over the same button at the time selenium is trying to click (I don't have to click it manually, just hover the mouse).  So, I am thinking of using Sikuli or autopy instead (both of which I have used with great success in the past).  The trouble is, both of these things move the real cursor around, and I don't want that.

I wonder if it is possible to disable mouse integration with a virtual machine in virtualbox, and then use one of these tools to move the virtual machine's cursor, and automate my applications inside the virtual machine without affecting my real cursor.  Does anyone know how to do this, or if it is possible?

Comment: I'm wondering the exact same thing.

Comment: Why not running a Sikuli script inside the Virtual Machine?